# How to make one view aware of another's changes?

Tags: backbone.js

Suppose you are making a music library app.

You have one view with a list on genres and another that shows the contents of the selected genre. When the user clicks a genre on the list, the contents in the other view should be updated accordingly.

What is the best way to do this so that there are minimal dependencies?

I have not found any other place to listen to the mouse clicks than the view that draws the individual genre. I can send an event from there, but what is the optimal way of getting that event to update the other view which draws the genre contents? Who should listen to that event, the genre content view or its collection?

EDIT: I instantiate both views from the router of the app and I did manage to get this to work by making the views aware of each other, but that's not optimal of course.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could make a simple model to hold the application state, you don't need anything fancy, just a bag of data that implements the usual Backbone event methods:

```
var AppState  = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var app_state = new AppState();
```

Then the genre list view would listen for click events (as you already have) and set the current genre on the app-state model when someone changes it:

```
var Genres = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    choose: function(ev) {
        // This would be the click handler for the genre,
        // `.html()` is just for demonstration purposes, you'd
        // probably use a data attribute in real life.
        app_state.set({genre: $(ev.target).html() });
    },
});
```

The view for the individual genre would listen for `"change:genre"` events on the app-state model and react as the genre changes:

```
var Genre = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'change_genre');
        app_state.on('change:genre', this.change_genre);
    },
    //...
    change_genre: function() {
        // Refill the genre display...
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mwBKm/1/

You can make models for any data you want and models are a convenient way of working with data events in Backbone. As an added bonus, this approach makes it fairly easy to persist your application's state: just add the usual Backbone persistence support to `AppState` and away you go.

---

If you only need a simple event bus to push non-data events around, you can use Backbone's [`Events`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) methods to build a simple event aggregator:

```
app.events = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Then, assuming you have a global `app` namespace, you can say things like this:

```
app.events.on('some-event', some_function);
```

and

```
app.events.trigger('some-event', arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer!
I'm using RequireJS for dependencies, but I guess I just create the AppState model in the router where I create the views and add that as a dependency to the views - the persistence is an awesome side-gain!

Comment: @wannabeartist: And you can add other bits of application-level data to AppState as needed (current track, search filters, ...) and everything will neatly fall into place.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have seen is in the method proposed by [Derick Bailey](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/).  In short you can create an event aggregator, which provides a centralized object for raising events to which different views can subscribe.  The beauty of this solution is that it is very simple to implement as it makes use of Backbone's existing event system.